# Make the Code adapt to the changes instead of hardcode as shown in below

Tags: excel, vba

what am i going to do if there are new data added into the excel, instead of changing my code( hard code), for let say if i add data in row 6, row 7, then i have to declare rng6 for range(A6:LY6).As i am still new in excel vba, need some examples for this case. Thank you very much. Hope the editing makes the question understandable. Sorry once again for din specify it clearly.

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim rng4 As Range
Dim rng5 As Range

Set rng1 = Range("A1:AC1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
Set rng2 = Range("A2:LY2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
Set rng3 = Range("A3:LY3").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
Set rng4 = Range("A4:LY4").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
Set rng5 = Range("A5:LY5").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)


rng1.Rows.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
rng2.Rows.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
rng3.Rows.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
rng4.Rows.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
rng5.Rows.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to delete blank cells from each row, but you dont know how many rows you have?

**The first step is to determine how many rows you need to edit?**

If column A always contains info (non-blank), you can simply write `lastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row` to get the last non-empty cell in column A

If column A contains blanks, you'll have to figure out a clever way to get the range you want to edit, `ActiveSheet.UsedRange`for example.

**Now loop through the rows and edit them.**

```
Sub test()
Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
'To avoid errors when no empty cells are found:
On Error Resume Next 
'Unless you have Another way to determine how many rows to delete:
lastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
'Loop through the rows:
For row=1 To lastRow
    'Select the empty cells in this row:
    Set rng = Range("A" & Row & ":LY" & Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    'Delete the empty cells:
    rng.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Next
End Sub
```

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: it does help, but i don't wan to declare rng2 till rng5 as i will have more data added in after A5, just ignore the A1:AC1. If i have more data, i need to declare some more like rng6, rng7, rng8 and so on

Answer (score 1):

Code for dynamic selecting all range data (finding last row and column), assuming your data has the same number of columns to all rows.

```
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim rng1 As Range

With ActiveSheet
    lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng1 = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
End With
```

Comment: hi, i've edited my code for your understanding, sorry for the inconvenience in understanding what i've done.

Comment: thanks, is the first row on purpose up to `AC` while all other rows are up to `LY`. can we assume that all future added rows will have same structure of data and number of columns ?

Comment: yes, you are right, future data is having same structure of data and number of columns, but ignore the AC row.